# visual studio community 2015 version 14.0.25422.01 Update 3 no intellisense

Tags: visual-studio

I have just downloaded visual studio community 2015 version 14.0.25422.01 Update 3. I have made a Winforms c# project. I can't get Intellisense to work. how do i go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

not sure why this would be the case after a fresh install but, this worked for me.

Tools->Import and Export settings->Reset all settings.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-resolve-intellisense-issue-in-visual-studio1